# Mongoose .find with a req.params array? and res.json an array of each value and count?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, express, mongoose

Ideally a user would be able to enter multiple tags in a search field, which are then delinienated client-side (before the .get call), to be sent over ajax with each keypress.

Working on the server-side (testing the API with Postman), if the .get serves up the variable tags as an array of [ 'tag1', 'tag2'], **can req.params.tags be an array?**

If so, what would it look like for the server - right now, am only getting a response from Postman for localhost:4200/api/v1/tag/tagName .. but not for /tag/tagName1+tagName2 or /tag/tagName1&tagName2

Here's the current API:

```
router.route('/tag/:tags')

    // get the list of tags for userGenerated tags (accessed at GET http://localhost:4200/api/v1/tag/:tags)
    .get(function(req, res) {

        Story.count( { tags: { $in: [  req.params.tags ] } }, function (err, count) {

            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            console.log('there is/are %d story/ies with this/these tag(s)', count);

            if (count >= 1) {

                Story.find( { tags: { $in: [  req.params.tags ] } }, 'tags', function(err, stories) {

                    if (err)
                        res.send(err);

                    res.json(stories); // something to return the count of each tag with the tag

                }); // find and return tags

            } // if count >= 1

            if (count < 1) {

                res.json({ message: count + ' results' });

            } // if count < 1 

        }); // .count

    }); // get list of tags
```

Secondly, do I need to use .aggregate (have yet to explore this really) to then res.json an ARRAY of the tags that I can loop over to get each tagName and the count for each specific tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This actually isn't a mongo-specific question, it's an express question (I'm assuming you are using express here).

There isn't a way for express to automatically parse a dynamic segment (the part prefixed with a `:` in the url) into an array, but you can easily do it yourself:

```
// example url: /tags/tag1,tag2
app.get('/tags/:tags', function(req, res){
  var tags = req.params.tags.split(','); // ['tag1','tag2']
  res.send('you entered tags :' + tags.join(','));
});
```

Here's a runnable example: http://runnable.com/U5SI2eAfzMh7Sfkt/example-reading-an-array-of-arguments-in-req-params-with-express-for-node-js-and-hello-world